# anti-pattern: updating (unrelated) state in a render() method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, recharts

I am overriding Recharts' Tooltip functionality to provide the hover data elsewhere on the page (in another component).

```
<Tooltip content={ this.showTooltipData.bind(this) } />
```

showToolTipData fires off an action creator which modifies a part of the state tree which the current render method is **not** sensitive to, but I still get the dreaded anti-pattern warning:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

This warning is both correct and incorrect, as the rendering component is not affected by the state change. The only reason I care about this is that the warning can spam the console (there are 10s of 1000s of points to hover over).

Is there a better way to do this? I have considered using the the target hover data component's "private" state (as opposed to the redux state now in use) but I need that data elsewhere as well. Moving the functionality to **componentWillMount()** is impossible.

Anyone found a safer way to override the ToolTip function?

Answer (score 0):

Freakin' crickets. Once I get the time I'll take this over to redux...